# cURL call failed error in 2checkout

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, payment-processing, 2checkout

Hi am using 2checkout sandbox to test payment solution. The token is created successfully and logged in my API log Console. But at last i see the error  `cURL call failed`

Here is my code

**index.html**

```
        <html>
        <head>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/api/2co.min.js"></script>

        </head>


        <body>
        <form id="myCCForm" action="payment.php" method="post">
            <input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" value="">
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Card Number</span>
                </label>
                <input id="ccNo" type="text" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Expiration Date (MM/YYYY)</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" size="2" id="expMonth" required />
                <span> / </span>
                <input type="text" size="2" id="expYear" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>CVC</span>
                </label>
                <input id="cvv" size="4" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
        </form>

        </body>


        <script>
            // Called when token created successfully.
            var successCallback = function(data) {
                var myForm = document.getElementById('myCCForm');

                // Set the token as the value for the token input
                myForm.token.value = data.response.token.token;

                // IMPORTANT: Here we call `submit()` on the form element directly instead of using jQuery to prevent and infinite token request loop.
                myForm.submit();
            };

            // Called when token creation fails.
            var errorCallback = function(data) {
                if (data.errorCode === 200) {tokenRequest();} else {alert(data.errorMsg);}
            };

            var tokenRequest = function() {
                // Setup token request arguments
                var args = {
                    sellerId: "My seller id added here",
                    publishableKey: "my publishableKey added here",
                    ccNo: $("#ccNo").val(),
                    cvv: $("#cvv").val(),
                    expMonth: $("#expMonth").val(),
                    expYear: $("#expYear").val()
                };

                // Make the token request
                TCO.requestToken(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
            };

            $(function() {
                // Pull in the public encryption key for our environment
                TCO.loadPubKey('sandbox');

                $("#myCCForm").submit(function(e) {
                    // Call our token request function
                    tokenRequest();

                    // Prevent form from submitting
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>


        </html>
```

**payment.php**

```
            require_once("2checkout-php/lib/Twocheckout.php");

            Twocheckout::privateKey('my private hey here');
            Twocheckout::sellerId('my seller id here');
            Twocheckout::sandbox(true);




            try {
                $charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
                    "merchantOrderId" => "123",
                    "token"      => $_POST['token'],
                    "currency"   => 'USD',
                    "total"      => '10.00',
                    "billingAddr" => array(
                        "name" => 'Testing Tester',
                        "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
                        "city" => 'Columbus',
                        "state" => 'OH',
                        "zipCode" => '43123',
                        "country" => 'USA',
                        "email" => 'example@2co.com',
                        "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
                    )
                ));

                if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') {
                    echo "Thanks for your Order!";
                    echo "<h3>Return Parameters:</h3>";
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($charge);
                    echo "</pre>";

                }
            } catch (Twocheckout_Error $e) {print_r($e->getMessage());}
```

Here is my API console

[image]

I tried adding

```
   Twocheckout::username('username');
   Twocheckout::password('password');
```

AND

```
   Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);
```

Nothing works. can some one Please help me to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you are using TLS v1.1 or v1.2 as these are the only protocols that the sandbox environment currently supports. You might check which version of PHP & SSL that you're using (php -v, openssl version) to ensure that you are up-to-date. There are some major changes for OpenSSL which can be found here: 
https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.1-notes.html